# IllegalArgumentException : Creating Spark Session

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am creating spark session using below snippet in python notebook on AWS EMR Cluster.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
                     .config("spark.jars.packages","org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.0") \
                     .getOrCreate()
```

Then reading data from S3 bucket like below

```
df_songs = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup","true") \
                .json("s3a://mydata/song_data/", schema=song_schema)
```

It gives me error :

```
IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "64M"
```

Environment : Amazon EMR Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hadoop-AWS` module added support for multiple cloud providers version `3.0` onwards.

Hadoop introduced s3a client to read/write from s3 from version 3.0 onwards.

> Hadoop’s “S3A” client offers high-performance IO against Amazon S3
> object store and compatible implementations.

To fix this issue I'd to create spark instance like with latest version

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
                     .config("spark.jars.packages","org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4") \
                     .getOrCreate()
```

Picked the latest version `3.x` of `hadoop-aws` from [mvn repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws)

Reference :
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html